# How to add restriction to Annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

Java annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface OneAnnotation{
    String aNumber();        
}
```

say I wanna only permit those string format which matches("[\d]+"), other string will be "failed" by either a complier error or some other notification.
Is there any of doing this---add restriction on returned value on annotation's method.

valid:

```
@OneAnnotation(aNumber = “1234”)
```

invalid:

```
@OneAnnotation(aNumber = “XXXX”)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to implement this using [annotation processing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/apt/index.html).

Other than that there's no way to add arbitrary restrictions to your annotations.

But: if you want a number, why don't you use a numeric type like `int` or `long` here (depending on your range requirements)?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know. (If you insist on compile-time errors, of course. At runtime you're free to do anything you want).

Comment: All I want is just to reminder the "OneAnnotation" user to be careful about the restrictions on the annotation. so it's better to have a compile-time error. But I learned that annotation processing is used to generate file, how could I use it to implement this simple restriction? for your question: actually, I want the returned value(String) of annotation method matches some regex pattern, the number is just an example. thanks

Comment: @rayeaster: yes, APT is *usually* used to produce Java source files, but nothing forces your processor to actually produce any output.